# Create .dll from c# library and only make specific functions callable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I have written a c#-console project that contains many classes and functions. I want to build a DLL from that project but only make functions from around 3 classes callable. These classes have dependencies from other classes, so these adherent classes have to be compiled but their functions should not be callable from the dll user.

I know how to create a simple DLL in Visual Studio 2019, that includes all functions from a project.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark the methods you want and the class as `public` to be visible in other projects that are referencing your dll/assembly (other methods must use other access modifiers to be hidden).
From [Microsoft's documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

> - **public**: The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the    same assembly **or another assembly that references it**.
> - **private**: The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.
> - **protected**: The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class, or in a class that is derived from that class.
> - **internal**: The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same    assembly, but not from another assembly.
> - **protected
>     internal**: The    type or member can be accessed by any code in the
>     assembly in which    it's declared, or from within a derived class in
>     another assembly.
> - **private protected**: The type or member can be accessed only within its    declaring assembly, by code in the same class or in a type that
>     is    derived from that class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the right accessor on each method. 
For example:

- **public** void Do() means it is accessable from other projects to (so for all)
- **internal** void Do() means that this function is only accessable inside the project
- **private** void Do() means the function is only callable inside the same class

So you have to choose one of them.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers